# Measure of diagonal dominance

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

Given any (singular or non-singular) matrix, is there a standard measure for how close the matrix is close to diagonal dominance? For example this matrix:
\begin{pmatrix}
5 &2 &2 \\
5 &1 &1 \\
5 &0 &0
\end{pmatrix}

I can't use permutation on the columns to make it diagonal dominant.
Is there a measure for sorting the columns and determine it to be as close to diagonal dominant as possible?

Comment: Good question. What if you used $\sum_i H_0\left( s(i) \right)s(i)$, where $s(i)=-|a_{ii}| + \sum_{j\ne i} |a_{ij}| $ and $H_0$ is the Heaviside step? So then it is zero if it is DD, and increasingly positive in the non DD case.

Comment: it's a nice idea, not sure if i can think of a way of proving optimality, i think my main problem is actually defining what is optimal..

Comment: Hmm well you could also look at $E=\min_{A \in P} \sum_i H_0(s(i)) s(i)$ ie the minimum over all column permutations $P$ of the matrix. This might be harder to prove things about though. Then it's DD iff $E=0$.

Comment: yeah that is what originally intended when i asked the question, find a measure and then use permutation to find the minimum for a given matrix... i'm just not sure that  the minimum would give better results then something else and of course i can think of lots of functions to minimize...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Measure of "how much diagonal" a matrix is](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1392491/measure-of-how-much-diagonal-a-matrix-is)