# Measure of closeness of a matrix to the block diagonal form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, block-matrices, sparse-matrices

Is there a well-behaved measure for closeness of a matrix to the block diagonal form? Permutations of rows and columns are assumed to be allowed.

[This thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1392491/measure-of-how-much-diagonal-a-matrix-is?newreg=71244d53f93849719d8c1d16c0dae56dhttps://) discusses the closeness to the diagonal matrix using the correlation coefficient, but I don't think the same approach would be generalizable to block diagonal matrices.

If such measure does not exist, what would be some of the standard measures for sparse matrices?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it is allowed.

Comment: Are you acquainted with [Cuthill–McKee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuthill–McKee_algorithm)?

Comment: Thanks! No I was not familiar with it. Could you please elaborate on how can one obtain a closeness measurement based on the Cuthill-McKee algorithm?

Comment: If there were a version of Cuthill–McKee for non-symmetric matrices, one could use it and then build a cost function where non-zero entries on the main diagonal are penalized $0$, whereas non-zero entries in the diagonal above or below the main diagonal would be penalized $1$, etc. The minimal cost would be an estimate of near-diagonal-ness. Zero cost for diagonal matrices. However, for block matrices, one would be interested in finding how many blocks there are and where they are, which is quite combinatorial.

Comment: Thanks for the elaboration. While this may work, I was mostly looking for a cost function that I could do gradient descent on. Through some searches, I saw this paper which is almost pursuing the same goal: 
[Robust Subspace Segmentation with Block-Diagonal Prior](https://openaccess.thecvf.com/content_cvpr_2014/papers/Feng_Robust_Subspace_Segmentation_2014_CVPR_paper.pdf).
I might end up implementing something similar.